# What is the equation of the hyperbolic path?

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections, hyperbolic-functions

I'm struggling with this question and any help would be greatly appreciated.

> Alpha particles are deflected along hyperbolic paths when they are directed towards the nuclei of gold atoms. If an alpha particle gets as close as 10 units to the nucleus along a hyperbolic path with asymptote y=2x/5, what is the equation of its path? Make a graph of the situation.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Where does the particle start and what’s its initial direction?

Comment: I suppose they mean asymptotes having equations $y=\pm2x/5$. If so it's easy: $a=10$ and $b/a=2/5$.